Can I choose github merge button for specific pull requests?
Question
Is it possible to configure github to disable one of these buttons based on some Pull Request details, for example when a branch name starts with release/*, but keep the second button enabled?
Context
In my project we have a rule to use "Squash and merge" for Pull Request with features and "Rebase and merge" button for Pull Requests prepared for releases, so we keep git history for commits.

Use of "Squash and merge" isn't very prudent in the long run. You'll run into problems rather sooner than later when developers request merging of updates of the feature branch. Ask you developers to clean up their feature branch histories before they submit merge requests, so that you can keep meaningful commits in the overall history.

@j6t I think you assume the feature branch as a long live branch, while in my case they are around one day long and then merged into main. We merge everything into main as soon as possible to provide continuous delivery we support of feature flags. And we use "squash and merge" to not end up with tons of mini-commits, but with commits where each of them is a representation of ticket from Jira.

In my workflow, even if I can solve a ticket in one day, it usually takes more than one commit. I aim to separate changes into small, self-contained and sensible parts, and not lump together a homungous change even if it originated from many smaller commits. It has nothing to do with long-livedness of a feature branch, only with what changes can stand on their own.

Of course, it's not one commit PR, that's why we use squash. Also, one PR is a rather small thing, not a big feature. So I don't see any benefits from keeping all mini commits that are part of PR on the main branch.

No, this is currently not possible. This may change in the future.
GitHub rolled out a feature called Rulesets that gives the opportunity to configure several behaviors, such as ability to force-push or require a PR, that you can then apply to branches or tags.
They may expand the feature to cover what you are looking for, but this is of course just speculation. At the time being, you have no way to enforce the merge style by neither branch naming nor paths.
